# How to print List as table in console application?

Tags: c#, .net

I need Method to print List as table in console application and preview in convenient format like this:

```
Pom_No          Item_Code          ordered_qty                      received_qty

1011            Item_Code1         ordered_qty1                    received_qty1 

1011            Item_Code2         ordered_qty2                    received_qty2

1011            Item_Code3         ordered_qty3                    received_qty3

1012            Item_Code1         ordered_qty1                    received_qty1 

1012            Item_Code2         ordered_qty2                    received_qty2

1012            Item_Code3         ordered_qty3                    received_qty3
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your main tool would be

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,5} {1,10} {2,-10}", s1, s2, s3);
```

The `,5` and `,10` are width specifiers. Use a negative value to left-align.

Formatting is also possible:

```
Console.WriteLine("y = {0,12:#,##0.00}", y);
```

Or a Date with a width of 24 and custom formatting:

```
String.Format("Now = {0,24:dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);
```

---

#### Edit, for C#6

With string interpolation you can now write

```
Console.WriteLine($"{s1,5} {s2,10} {s3,-10}");  
Console.WriteLine($"y = {y,12:#,##0.00}");
```

You don't need to call `String.Format()` explicitly anymore:

```
string s = $"Now = {DateTime.Now,24:dd HH:mm:ss}, y = {y,12:#,##0.00}" ;
```

Comment: Similar to [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This answer would be a lot better with sample output

Comment: First solution doesn't seem to work with Debug.WriteLine. Is this specific to Console.WriteLine?

Comment: Debug.WriteLine is different. You can use `Debug.Print(" format ", x, y)`.

Comment: This seems to work only if the string length is the same of all items in the list.

Answer (score 38):

The easiest this you can do is to use an [existing library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConsoleTables/)

```
Install-Package ConsoleTables
```

And then you can define your table like so:

```
ConsoleTable.From<Order>(orders).Write();
```

And it will give this output

```
| Id       | Quantity | Name              | Date                |
|----------|----------|-------------------|---------------------|
| 3355     | 6        | Some Product 3355 | 18-04-2016 00:52:52 |
| 3355     | 6        | Some Product 3355 | 18-04-2016 00:52:52 |
| 3355     | 6        | Some Product 3355 | 18-04-2016 00:52:52 |
| 3355     | 6        | Some Product 3355 | 18-04-2016 00:52:52 |
| 3355     | 6        | Some Product 3355 | 18-04-2016 00:52:52 |
```

Or define a custom table

```
var table = new ConsoleTable("one", "two", "three");
table.AddRow(1, 2, 3)
     .AddRow("this line should be longer", "yes it is", "oh");

table.Write();
```

For further examples checkout [c# console table](https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/ConsoleTables)

Comment: Need a .NET Standard 2.0 version ...

Answer (score 2):

Use \t to put in tabs to separate the columns

Comment: Tabs are only going to help you out when all data is of (almost) the same length.