# VB.NET Print Formatted Table On Console Window

Tags: vb.net

I have data that is stored in a 2-Dimensional List that I want to print to the console window where it is all lined up properly.

Example:

```
Dim aList As New List Of(List Of String))
aList = AfunctionThatFetchesData
```

aList

```
 {column 1}         {column 2} {column 3}
 This is some data   0          3
 Some more           1          3
 One more            2          3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print List as table in console application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160770/how-to-print-list-as-table-in-console-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx), where you will see that it uses the [composite formatting feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx), which support alignment parameters.  So, you can align things using, e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-10} {2,-10}", "{column 1}", "{column 2}", "{column 3}")
Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-10} {2,-10}", "This is some data", 0, 3)
```

which results in:

```
{column 1}           {column 2} {column 3}
This is some data    0          3
```

Adjusting the spacing and alignments in the format string will get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to be able to manually enter data into a table:

```
Console.Write("Enter Data For Column 1: ")
    Dim Data1 As String = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Enter Data For Column 2: ")
    Dim Data2 As String = Console.ReadLine

    Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-10} {2,-10}", "{Data Type}", "{Column 1}", "{Column 2}")
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-10} {2,-10}", "Data Entered:", Data1, Data2)

    Console.WriteLine("ENTER To Exit: ")
    Console.ReadLine()
```

[It should look like this (Click Me).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk7Mu.png)