# How to make that displays a table with specific values?

Tags: c#

Construct a table of values ​​for the function `f (x) = tg (x)` on the interval `[0, pi / 4]` with the number of partitions of `m = 10`.

```
namespace lab_6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            double x, f = 0;
            double m = 10;
            double z = (Math.PI / 4) / m;
            for (x = 0; x <= Math.PI / 4; x += z)
            {   f = Math.Tan(x);
                Console.WriteLine("f={0:f}", f);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `(0 - Math.PI / 4)` --> `(Math.PI / 4)`

Comment: do not quite understand

Comment: You want `[0, pi / 4]`. dx = (end - start) / m, not (start - end)/m

Comment: but how to make the result of the output table

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: the value of x at certain intervals function

Comment: try compile then do it.

Comment: There are no tables in console output. You can just create lines with dashes and bars if you want

Comment: if you do not difficult you could not write the complete code

Comment: I conditionally said "table". you just have a list of values ​​of x at a given interval

Comment: I already heard about the output. Like `Console.WriteLine("f({0:f})={1:f}", x, f);` ? You add  output  of sample to question.

Comment: The actual question isn't very clear here. If it's about formatting the output, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10160777/60761). And move the Readkey() outside the loop.

Comment: double z =- (Math.PI / 4) / m;
            for (x = 0; x <= Math.PI / 4; x -= z)

Comment: all thank you very much, error corrected